# Effective search of number pairs

Tags: c++, algorithm

I have a problem, where i have big list of number pairs. something like that:

```
(0,  1)
(10, 5)
(5, 6)
(8, 6)
(7, 5)
.....
```

I need to make that i can make very fast lookups if the pair exist in list.
My first idea was make `map< std::pair<int,int> >` container. and do searches using `container.find()`.

Second idea was to make `vector<vector<int>` container where i can search is the pair exist by using `std::find(container[id1].begin(),container[id1].end(),id2)`;

The second way is a bit faster than first, but i need more effective way if that possible.

So question is there more effective way to find is a number pair exist in list?

The number of pairs i know when starting program, so i dont care a lot about pair insertion/deletion, i just need very fast searches.

Comment: What do you mean the pairs are know when starting the program? Are they hard-coded?

Comment: when i start program i have big list of such integer pairs. so i know how many i have such pairs.

Comment: do take note that Map is not Pair. The first element on the map is a key (which must be different for each element), but this is not the case with pair. And C++ have std::pair as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want **faster-than-set lookups** (faster than `O(lg n)`) and don't care about items being in a random order, then a hashtable is the way to go.

This is not part of the standard, but a `hash_set` is available in most compilers. The reference for it is [here](http://www.sgi.com/tech/stl/hash_set.html).

If you want to have **really** fast searches, you can try a [Bloom filter](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bloom_filter). However, they sometimes result in false positives (i.e. detecting that there is an item pair when there is none), and require lots of memory. A suitable Bloom filter implementation would be:

```
const int MAX_HASH = 23879519; // note it's prime; must be 2-5 times larger than number of your pairs
vector<bool> Bloom(MAX_HASH); // vector<bool> compresses bools into bits

// multiply one by a large-ish prime, add the second, return modulo another prime
// then use it as the key for the filter
int hash(long long a, long long b) {
    return (a*15485863LL + b) % MAX_HASH;
}

// constant-time addition
void add_item(pair<int,int> p) {
    Bloom[hash(p.first, p.second)] = true;
}

// constant-time check
bool is_in_set(pair<int,int> p) {
    return Bloom[hash(p.first, p.second)];
}
```

Comment: with the advance of C++0x, I would rather recommend `std::unordered_set` or (if unavailable) `boost::unordered_set` as it was the basis for the development of the new Standard, and is portable.

Answer (score 4):

If you do not care about insertion you could use a sorted std::vector and std::binary_search, or std::lower_bound.

```
int main()
{
    using namespace std;
    vector<pair<int, int>> pairs;
    pairs.push_back(make_pair(1, 1));
    pairs.push_back(make_pair(3, 1));
    pairs.push_back(make_pair(3, 2));
    pairs.push_back(make_pair(4, 1));

    auto compare = [](const pair<int, int>& lh, const pair<int, int>& rh)
        {
            return lh.first != rh.first ? 
                   lh.first < rh.first : lh.second < rh.second;
        };

    sort(begin(pairs), end(pairs), compare);
    auto lookup = make_pair(3, 1);
    bool has31 = binary_search(begin(pairs), end(pairs), lookup, compare);

    auto iter31 = lower_bound(begin(pairs), end(pairs), lookup, compare);

    if (iter31 != end(pairs) && *iter31 == lookup)
        cout << iter31->first << "; " << iter31->second << "at position "
            << distance(begin(pairs), iter31);
}
```

Comment: +1: A sorted `vector` is faster than a `set` because of its nicer cache behavior (elements are packed *tightly* together). If the number of elements is *really* big, a hash table could be faster though.

Answer (score 2):

`std::set` is probably the way to go, and it should perform reasonably well even if the number of elements increase (whereas the performance of `std::vector` will slow down quite quickly unless you sort it beforehand and do some sort of binary or tree search). Keep in mind you'll have to define a `<` operator to use `std::set`.

If you can use c++0x, `std::unordered_set` might be worth a try also, particularly if you don't care about order. You'll find `unordered_set` in Boost. This doesn't require a `<` operator to be defined. If you make your `unordered_set` an appropriate size and define your own simple hash function that does not produce many collisions it might be faster than even a binary search on a sorted vector.

Comment: Strictly speaking you do not need to provide `operator<`. You can make do with a custom comparison functor passed as the second template argument to the `std::set`.

Answer (score 1):

You could use some implementation of hash_set to get it faster
for instance boost::unordered_set where the key is the std::pair.
This is the fastest from the easiest approaches.

Answer (score 1):

Here's another solution iff your individual numbers are `int`s.

1. Construct a `long long` with the two `int`s (the first `int` could be the high 32 bits and the second `int` the lower 32 bits)
2. Insert this into an `unorderd_set` (or `set`, or sorted `vector` - profile to find your match)
3. find.

Should be some percentage faster than working with pairs/tuples etc. esp.

Answer (score -1):

Why not sorting the tuples according to 1st element, then 2nd, then a binary search should be O(log(n)).

Comment: Why downvoted? Suggested the same as hansmaad did except he provided the implementation and I was one minute earlyer.